# Annoying issue with my Gionee P5L

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, launcher

My phone's model is Gionee P5L. For the few days I am facing this stupid and annoying problem. I don't know why and how but I have multiple copies of the same apps in my phone... For example I have 2 facebook lite, 2 opera mini, 3 google settings, 2 play store. Can anyone let me know how to fix this ? Here are two screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a third party launcher?

Comment: no. default phone launcher